# Redirecting to another component after a success Login with ReactJs/ExpressJs/Axios?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redirect, axios

I'm new to reactJs and NodeJs in general and I know this question is already asked before but it's not the answer I wanted, so I wrote a Login.jsx page with react and passing the username and password with axios to submitted to the backend which I'm using Express Js, all I want here is after a success login I want to redirect the user to the home.jsx page and I really didn't find the solution I was searching for !
***Login.jsx***

```
function Login(props) {

    const loginSubmit=()=>{

        Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/login",{
            user:username,
            pass:password
        }).then((rs)=>{
            //HERE WHEN THE LOGIN SUCCEED I WANT TO DO SOMETHING TO REDIRECT TO HOME.JSX
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
     return (  
         //some react elements  
        )};
```

***Server.js***

```
app.post("/login", (req, res)=>{
    FIREBASE_AUTH_TO_SUBMIT_USER_DATA.
    then(()=>{
        res.send("succefully logged");
        //OR HERE TO REDIRECT TO HOME.JSX
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        res.status(401).send("failed login");
    });
```

I found that it may be resolved by react routing, but again I searched about react routing and it didn't seem like a solution for me!

Comment: Where is your Home.jsx rendered?

Comment: @PavloZhukov it's in the same path as Login.jsx in the project directory and the Server.js is in the ./backend/Server.js

Comment: Have you tried react-router? It's difficult to do redirects in SPA's without a dedicated router. With react-router, and its `useNavigate` function, this could become a lot easier

Comment: Ok. But where do you render your Home.jsx component? If you want to redirect to it, you need to render it somewhere and show it when your redirect happens. If it is just a file, it means that it isn't rendered anywhere, and you need to figure out how do you want to render it.